# Insert username in a ejs template with express and node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to insert the username in a layout, I'm using ejs templating with node and express. I've tried the following:

**Mongodb model:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide username'],
    unique: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please provide password'],
  },
  dateRegistered: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date()
  }
  //image: String
});

UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

//encrypt password
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const user = this
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, (error, hash) => {
    user.password = hash
    next()
  });
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User
```

**EDIT: login.js:**

```
module.exports = (req,res) =>{
  res.render('login')
}
```

**EDIT: loginUser.js**

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const User = require('../models/User')

module.exports = (req, res) => {
  const {
    username,
    password
  } = req.body;

  User.findOne({
    username: username
  }, (error, user) => {
    if (user) {
      bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (error, same) => {
        if (same) {
          req.session.userId = user._id
          res.redirect('/')
        } else {
          res.redirect('/auth/login')
        }
      })
    } else {
      res.redirect('/auth/login')
    }
  })
}
```

**EDIT: authMiddleware.js:**

```
const User = require('../models/User')

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    User.findById(req.session.userId, (error, user ) =>{
      if(error || !user )
        return res.redirect('/auth/login')

      next()
    })
}
```

**EDIT: redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware.js**

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) =>{
    if(req.session.userId){
      return res.redirect('/') // if user logged in, redirect to home page
    }
    next()
}
```

**EDIT: index.js:**

```
const loginController = require('./controllers/login')
const loginUserController = require('./controllers/loginUser')

app.get('/auth/login', redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, loginController)
app.post('/users/login',redirectIfAuthenticatedMiddleware, loginUserController)
```

**navbar.ejs:**

```
<% if(loggedIn) { %>
    <p> <%= username %> </p>
<% } %>
```

The result is an empty paragraph with no value
EDIT: added routes, managed through controllers

Answer (score 0):

where is your render function? You need to pass the variable to the template. For that, with EJS the solution is:

**router handler**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

**in the template page: index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

so in your case it should be something like

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { 
      loggedIn: true
      username: res.locals.username 
  });
});
```

and that

```
<% if(loggedIn) { %>
    <p> <%= username %> </p>
<% } %>
```

Comment: Hi, I manage routes through controllers, question edited. Thanks